# Kubernetes cluster certificate authority on DigitalOcean

Tags: kubernetes, openssl, certificate, digital-ocean, rbac

I'm trying to configure RBAC to add new user with limited access. I'm following this tutorial: https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/#use-case-1-create-user-with-limited-namespace-access

It asks me to approve user sign request using Kubernetes CA:

> Locate your Kubernetes cluster certificate authority (CA). This will be responsible for approving the request and generating the necessary certificate to access the cluster API. Its location is normally /etc/kubernetes/pki/. In the case of Minikube, it would be ~/.minikube/. Check that the files ca.crt and ca.key exist in the location.

So I need to run the command:

```sh
openssl x509 -req -in employee.csr -CA CA_LOCATION/ca.crt -CAkey CA_LOCATION/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out employee.crt -days 500
```

But in DigitalOcean I can't access Kubernetes internals (can't touch node droplets).

Is it possible to approve certificate sign request with DigitalOcean?

Comment: I think this should help: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/kubernetes-how-do-i-access-the-ca-to-sign-a-new-user-certificate

Comment: Pleased to hear it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the build in CA in your cluster to create client certificates.

Background information on how to use the CA: [cluster-administration-certificates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/certificates/).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Make sure that you have created JSON user configuration file

Example JSON file:

```
{
    "CN": "example-user",
    "key": {
        "algo": "rsa",
        "size": 4096
    },
    "names": [{
        "O": "example-user",
        "email": "some@email"
    }]
}
```

1. Generate CSR for it
2. Use kubectl command to submit a CSR
3. the request field is base64 encoded version of your csr file
4. View your CSR, execute command: `kubectl get csr`
5. Approve CSR, execute command: `kubectl certificate approve example-user`
6. Decode certificate,execute command: `kubectl get csr example-user -o
   jsonpath='{.status.certificate}' | base64 -d > client.pem`
7. You can now use the client-key.pem and client.pem to build a
   kubeconfig
8. You can then create RBAC rolebindings on your cluster assigning to
   either –user=example-user or –group=example-user (assuming you used
   “O”: “example-user” is defined in this example)

Here you can find more information: [certificates](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/kubernetes-how-do-i-access-the-ca-to-sign-a-new-user-certificate).